# Bot not responding in Bot Framework Emulator

Tags: .net, visual-studio, botframework, azure-bot-service, botframeworkemulator

I have a Web App Bot in Azure which I would like to develop locally with .Net / C# in MS Visual Studio 2019. I downloaded the source code from the build blade in the Azure portal and followed exact the instructions in the read.me file. I opened the .sln file in VS 2019 and the build and run were successful and I received a port number for the bot URL. I opened the emulator and tried both 'open bot' and 'create new bot configuration' and in both cases the I am not receiving any response when trying to test the bot in the emulator. I also downloaded ngrok but I keep getting the 'send failed' and that is all. Does anybody know a solution? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if you have .bot file?

If you do not have a .bot file, could you please do:

1. click on 'create a new bot configuration' in the Welcome page of Bot Framework Emulator or File
2. click on New Bot Configuration
3. fill in the required fields and click save and connect.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. There is not .bot file. I tried also 'create new bot configuration' but this still yielded the same result. Any other recommended solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Emulator to test the local bot, you must make sure that you are either specifying appid/password (if configured in configuration (appsettings.json/.env), or leaving them blank (if blank in configuration).

If using NGrok, you want to [change the endpoint URL within Azure](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/), then make sure that it is running locally.

Do you see any errors/exceptions within Emulator (bottom right pane) or with in NGrok, when using either of these approaches?

Comment: thank you for your input. i entered the app id and passwork found from configuration in azure portal. still didnt work. however, i dont have an appsettings.json in my source code. i also tried using Ngrok and it said it was running and connected but still no luck. i will try to change the endpoint url within azure to see if that helps.

Comment: I also tried to change the endpoint URL in azure however this did not seem to work. the only error i ever get is the post 400 error when I dont connect NGrok otherwise when NGrok is connected, I dont get any specific error only that my message cannot be sent.

Comment: That's odd you don't have an appsettings.json. My assumption was that downloaded code would have one. Anyhow, go ahead and add one. Contents are basically `{ "MicrosoftAppId": "",  "MicrosoftAppPassword": ""}`. Just fill in the values. If you're using NGrok, then you _must_ configure the same MicrosoftAppId/MicrosoftAppPassword that is being used in Azure. If you are using Emulator, you _can_ leave them blank if blank in appsettings.json.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this to see if it helps